# Perl regex - Find functions in C file and print their definitions

Tags: regex, perl

-- UPDATED --

I want to find C functions in file and print their definitios

For example:

For this input:

```
#include <stdlib>

int function(int a)
{
    return a;
}

void func2()
{
    int b = 1;
}

int func3(int a,int b)
{
   a = a +b;
        while(x) {
            x--;
        }
   return a;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int x=(a+1);
    return 0;
}
```

The output should be:

```
int function(int a);
void func2();
int func3(int a,int b);
```

This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
open(FILE, "<", $ARGV[0]) or die "file open error";

if ( @ARGV ) #if there are args
{
    if ( -f $ARGV[0] ) #if its regular file
    {

    while(<FILE>)
      {
      if ($_ =~ /(.+)\s(.+)\(/){
      print $1; # type in arg $1
      print "\n";
      print $2; # name in arg $2
      print "\n";
    }
      }
    }
    else{
print "Arg is not a file\n";}
}
else{
print "no args\n";}
```

I end with function type in arg $1 and function name in $2. I want to get the full name and args in '()' brackets in $2. How to avoid 'main' word? the     '^[(main)] doesnt work. In the end I want to print it all with ';' at the end.

It needs to check for {} brackets to not print for example:    int x=(a+1);

Comment: You don't even have a slot for the arguments of the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `/(\S+)\s+(\S+\([^)]*\))/` and then `print $1+$2+";\n"`.

To prevent `main` with negative lookahead:

```
/(\S+)\s+((?!main)\S+\([^)]*\))/
```

If lookahead is not supported:

```
/(\S+)\s+((m|ma|mai|[^m].*|m[^a].*|ma[^i].*|mai[^n].*)\([^)]*\))/
```

The part responsible for avoiding `main`:

```
(m|ma|mai|[^m].*|m[^a].*|ma[^i].*|mai[^n].*)
```

Comment: Good job. Can you do it with avoiding the 'main' word?

Comment: Does perl support lookahead?

Comment: `/(\S+)\s+((?!main)\S+\([^)]+\))/` Its avoiding main function very well, but doesn't print other functions than 'int' type. There is void function that should be printed too.

Comment: Worked when I changed last `+` into `*`. Void function was empty :)

Comment: @Piodo Thanks, fixed.

Comment: Oops, you're faster than me :p

Comment: I've updated the question. There are new errors. This code also prints the `int x=(a+1);` . It needs to check for {} brackets (and dont print while loop inside). Can you help me with that?

Comment: Yes, replace the `\S+` which checks for the **function name** by `[a-zA-Z_]+`.

Comment: Well, you can replace both `\S+` by that, it doesn't matter.

Comment: The variable still fits into [a-zA-Z_]+

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111130/discussion-between-kenny-lau-and-piodo).